# How to close an Iframe to activate "Leaving page with unsaved changes"

Tags: asp.net, iframe

I can see this is a commonly asked question, of how to "close" an Iframe. However I have the problem where I have an iframe where a user answers questions and if they close the iframe they should be prompted so save their changes if havent before they are able to close. Currently the user is able to close out of the iframe without getting prompted, but if they try to open another iframe to answer other questions the old iframe appears with the prompt of trying to leave with unsaved changes. I have tried

```
data-dismiss="modal"
.attr('src','about:blank')
.remove()
```

How am I able to close my iframe in order to trigger the prompt to have the user save their data before closing out of the iframe.

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple way to do this and unless the page in the iframe is also under your control the simple answer is that you can’t do this.

If you do control the page then it is still reasonably complex, as you will need to use the postMessage API to send a message to the iframe and then adapt the application in the iframe to process this incoming message and display the “save” prompt to the user. Once the use has interacted with the prompt, you then need to use postMessage again to fire another message back to the parent page to tell the JavaScript there that it is now safe to close the page.

Comment: To make sure I understand this correctly, you are saying to have the close button on the iframe to trigger the code to prompt the user to "save", instead of the action of closing down the window/tab. But in order to have the iframe to work that way I need to communicate to the parent page.

Comment: It’s up to you where you have the close button, either way the two pages need to talk to each other to agree when it is ok to close the iframe. You might find the `iframe-resizer` library helpful with what you are trying to do.

Comment: David I am getting tripped on getting the parent and child talking properly. I have a Iframe(Child) inside of a Modal(Parent) and currently have the child has an EventListener(beforeunload) and tried to get the parent with the close button to call the beforeunload as well and it is not talking properly. Any guidance?

Comment: Are these both on the same domain?

Comment: No they are part of the same domain